# HttpClient MultipartFormDataContent only for key value pairs, replacement of working webrequest code

Tags: .net, .net-core, httpclient, rest

I am unable to send **MultipartFormDataContent** post request with only key/value pairs (no files) to specific API.

I have tried:

- FormUrlEncodedContent key value pairs
- MultipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(value), "nameofvalue");
- Looked examples andthe only working solution was using web request. Web request is old client, I
  prefer to use elegant -> HttpClient.

*Attaching code sample which works using web request and which one I can not replace with HTTP client:*

```
public static class FormUpload
{
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters)
    {
        var formDataBoundary = $"----------{Guid.NewGuid():N}";
        var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;

        var formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

        return PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData);
    }
    private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
        }

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        using var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }

    private static byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
    {
        using var formDataStream = new MemoryStream();
        var needsClrf = false;

        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {
            // Thanks to feedback from commenters, add a CRLF to allow multiple parameters to be added.
            // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
            if (needsClrf)
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

            needsClrf = true;

            var postData = $"--{boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{param.Key}\"\r\n\r\n{param.Value}";
            formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
        }

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
        var footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
        formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));

        // Dump the Stream into a byte[]
        formDataStream.Position = 0;
        var formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
        formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        return formData;
    }
}
```

Comment: In postman its just a simple form-data request and it works easily, I can not reproduce it on c#. Sample screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/3RsYqyJ/postman.png

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it was server side issue.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
were must.

Sticked with FormUrlEncodedContent approach.